# How to play a youtube video on iphone, not in fullscreen

Tags: iphone, webview, youtube

I'd like to play a YouTube video in my iPhone app inside a view or a webview.
I know it's possible to play inline videos on the iPad, but I haven't been able to do that on the iPhone. As soon as the video starts playing, the movie player goes to fullscreen so my UI is not visible.

Does anyone know how to overcome this limitation? Is there any other app that does that on the app store?

Thanks!

Comment: Checkout Deja - that app does it. But the way that app achieves this goal is rather complicated and IMHO against the Appstore submissions guidelines / HIG specs. Nevertheless, it got approved.

Comment: Thanks, I checked in out and it looks very impressive. Any ideas how that accomplish it?

Comment: Yes, and you wont like it :D ... That app actually fetches the video/s  from YouTube using a faked user agent (custom HTTP connection). It then instantiates a local HTTP server. Once that is setup, it starts MPMoviePlayerController which connects directly to that local server which is fed by the custom HTTP connection downloading the video from YouTube.

Comment: Actually it sounds pretty clever. I don't know if I'm going to use that or not, but still a solid idea. How did you figure this out?

Comment: I used the mighty power of Charles Proxy for finding those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for adding the you tube into your application.

For this you need to setup a webview in your view.
Then call the `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` method on the `UIWebView` instance with some carefully constructed HTML that contains the YouTube embedded player code snippet and some supporting HTML to make sure that the video thumbnail appears correctly. Set the base URL to the URL of your website (it doesn't do anything here -- ordinarily `UIWebView` uses it to handle relative URL links correctly).

```
NSString *youTube = @"<html><head>
<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 212\"/></head>
<body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\">
<div><object width=\"212\" height=\"172\">
<param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"></param>
<param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param>
<embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM\"
type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"212\" height=\"172\"></embed>
</object></div></body></html>";

[webView loadHTMLString:youTube baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.your-url.com"]];
```

For further reference : [YouTube](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html)

Comment: That doesn't help prevent the video from going full screen. What I'm trying to do is to get the video to play as part of my UI on the iPhone, instead of taking up the whole screen.